# Prove that this limit exist

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

\begin{aligned}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}
\end{aligned}

I tried to find the $\delta$ and $\epsilon$. My attempts to limit has been in vain and I can not clear the $h$.

tried: 
\begin{aligned}
\left|\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}\right|<\varepsilon \newline  
\left|\frac{\sin(x)\cdot\cos(h)+\sin(h)\cdot\cos(x) - \sin(x)}{h}\right|<\varepsilon  \newline
\left|\frac{\sin x\cdot(\cos(h)-1)}{h} + \frac{\cos x(\sin(h)-h)}{h}\right| < \varepsilon \newline
\end{aligned} 
applying triangular inequality and delimiting
\begin{aligned}
0<\sin x < 1 
\end{aligned} 
\begin{aligned}
 0<\cos x<1
\end{aligned} 
... I can not find my $| h | <  \delta$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Do you *have* to use $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$?

Comment: Hint. Use the addition formula for $\sin$ on the first term in the numerator. Then you will have to know something about $\sin(h)/h$. For that you need an epsilon delta argument or something geometric, depending on how you have defined $\sin$. Are you sure you have asked the question as it was asked of you?

Comment: Thanks!. Yes, using ε and δ.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that (take a look to this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)):

$$\sin\alpha - \sin\beta = 2 \cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}.$$

Therefore:

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{2}{h} \cos\frac{2x+h}{2}\sin\frac{h}{2}.$$

Since

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} = 1,$$

then, the previous limit reduces to:

$$\lim_{h\to0} \cos\frac{2x+h}{2} = \cos(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\sin (x+h)=\sin x \cos h + \cos x \sin h$$ and also $$\cos h=1-2\sin^2 \frac h2$$ so that $$sin (x+h)-\sin x= -2\sin x \sin^2 \frac h2 +\cos x\sin h$$

Now you need a standard result for $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {\sin h}h$